# problems with values in jquery with django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

please help, how i can send variable from view to javascript?
Like jquery i used simple example auto-filed field.
Example (jquery):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function findValue(li) {
        if( li == null ) return alert("No match!");
        if( !!li.extra ) var sValue = li.extra[0];
        else var sValue = li.selectValue;
        alert("The value you selected was: " + sValue);
}

function selectItem(li) {
        findValue(li);
}

function formatItem(row) {
        return row[0] + " (id: " + row[1] + ")";
}

function lookupAjax(){
        var oSuggest = $("#CityAjax")[0].autocompleter;
        oSuggest.findValue();

        return false;
}

function lookupLocal(){
        var oSuggest = $("#CityLocal")[0].autocompleter;

        oSuggest.findValue();

        return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#CityAjax").autocomplete(
                "autocomplete_ajax.cfm",
                {
                        delay:10,

                        minChars:2,
                        matchSubset:1,
                        matchContains:1,
                        cacheLength:10,
                        onItemSelect:selectItem,
                        onFindValue:findValue,
                        formatItem:formatItem,
                        autoFill:true
                }
        );

        $("#CityLocal").autocompleteArray(
                ["Albany", "Alexandria", "Alger", "Alledonia", "Alliance", "Alpha", "Alvada", "Alvordton", "Amanda", "Amelia", "Amesville", "Amherst", "Amlin", "Amsden",
                ],
                {
                        delay:10,
                        minChars:1,
                        matchSubset:1,
                        onItemSelect:selectItem,
                        onFindValue:findValue,
                        autoFill:true,
                        maxItemsToShow:100
                }
        );
});
</script>
```

Sorry and this is my html tags :

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return false;">
                <input type="text" id="CityLocal" value="" autocomplete="off" class="ac_input">
                <input type="button" value="Get Value" onclick="lookupLocal();">
</form>
```

and there is exmaple value django (array) :

```
var = [u'zabbix[process,java poller,avg,busy]', u'vm.memory.size[total]', u'vmware.hv.hw.cpu.threads[{$URL},{HOST.HOST}]', u'agent.ping', u'zabbix[wcache,history,pfree]', u'agent.version', u'vmware.hv.network.in[{$URL},{HOST.HOST},bps]', u'vm.memory.size[available]', u'vmware.hv.hw.vendor[{$URL},{HOST.HOST}]', u'vmware.hv.hw.model[{$URL},{HOST.HOST}]', u'system.boottime', u'system.cpu.util[,user]', u'system.hostname', u'zabbix[queue,10m]' ]
```

Can someone explain me please, how i can do this?

Comment: I deleted my answer after analyzing that your problem is entirely different via the comments to my answer, if I can define, you tried `{{ keys-var }}` but what I see is, you are using something called `zabbix` and your problem is the array returned from it's API is not valid. Please provide valid input and output. The result you are getting and expected.

Comment: The value was return to javascript normal, but the jquery can't use them. (i'm try alert the variable and there is corect)

Comment: So @oliloshka, Please provide us the value returned to javascript. We will try and help. Edit your question and provide more info on what is returned and so on.